# Implementing google auth using passport - error

Tags: node.js, api, passport.js

I'm trying to implement google sign-in/ sign-up for my web app but I'm getting the following error:

```
GooglePlusAPIError: Project [project#] is not found and cannot be used  for API calls.
```

This is my auth setup:

```
    'googleAuth' : {
        'clientID'       : '***********',
        'clientSecret'   : '***********',
        'callbackURL'    : 'http://localhost:8080/auth/google/callback' 
}
```

I've created the app on the google developer console and set the redirect URI to the same as that mentioned in the above auth setup. For good measure, here's my strategy for google signup:

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({

    clientID        :  configAuth.googleAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret    :  configAuth.googleAuth.clientSecret,
    callbackURL     :  configAuth.googleAuth.callbackURL,
},
function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    process.nextTick(function() {

        User.findOne({ 'google.id' : profile.id }, function(err, user) {
            if(err)
                return done(err);

            if(user) {
                // if a user is found log them in
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                // if no user, create it
                var newUser         = new User();
                newUser.google.id         = profile.id;
                newUser.google.token      = token;
                newUser.google.name       = profile.displayName;
                newUser.google.email      = profile.emails[0].value;

                //save user
                newUser.save(function(err) {
                    if(err)
                        throw err;
                    return done(null, newUser);
                });
            }
        });
    });
}));
```

I've trawled the internet for answers and find nothing at all. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Confirm the version of this library that you are using:

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google

The latest version of this library does not accept these options.

See snippet from documentation below:

```
* Options:
 *   - `returnURL`  URL to which Google will redirect the user after authentication
 *   - `realm`      the part of URL-space for which an OpenID authentication request is valid
 *   - `profile`    enable profile exchange, defaults to _true_
 *
 * Examples:
 *
 *     passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
 *         returnURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/return',
 *         realm: 'http://localhost:3000/'
 *       },
 *       function(identifier, profile, done) {
 *         User.findByOpenID(identifier, function (err, user) {
 *           done(err, user);
 *         });
 *       }
 *     ));
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but it doesn't seem to be the issue. The error I receive doesn't point to this at all and as soon as I substitute 'callbackURL' for anything else, it tells me that I am missing this param

Comment: What version of the library are you using?

Comment: You are using an outdated library. Google has disconitnued open ID support. I think you mean to use this https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth as opposed to https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but I'm still really confused by this. I followed the installation instructions for the new version (i.e. npm insall passport-google-oauth --save) and in my package.json file I can see that passport-google-oauth is indeed listed (not just passport-google) so it looks to me like I'm set up correctly?

Comment: It's fine. You should probably just switch to googleapis by Google. https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis